# Por que ocorre uma 'NSInvalidArgumentException' nesse código?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

Tenho uma classe que gerencia todo meu banco de dados, meu projeto é em Swift porém tenho duas classes em Objective-C para fazer a "ponte" entre as classes e o meu *Helper*.

Após alguns testes no simulador do iOS tive a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSString
>   stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'

Por que isso ocorreu?

Segue minhas duas classes:

**`SQLiteObjc.h`**:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "sqlite3.h"

@interface SQLiteObjc : NSObject

+ (void) bindText:(sqlite3_stmt *)stmt idx:(int)idx withString: (NSString*)s;

+ (NSString*) getText:(sqlite3_stmt *)stmt idx:(int)idx;

@end
```

**`SQLiteObjc.m`**:

```
#import "SQLiteObjc.h"

@implementation SQLiteObjc

+ (void) bindText:(sqlite3_stmt *)stmt idx:(int)idx withString: (NSString*)s {
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, idx, [s UTF8String], -1, nil);
}

+ (NSString*) getText:(sqlite3_stmt *)stmt idx:(int)idx {
    char *s = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, idx);
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:s];
    return string;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está tentando inicializar uma string com um valor nulo na seguinte linha:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:s];
```

Portanto, você deve testar se você possui uma c string válida antes de tentar construir uma NSString. Aldo do tipo:

```
+ (NSString*) getText:(sqlite3_stmt *)stmt idx:(int)idx {
    char *s = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, idx);
    if (s != NULL)
        return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:s];
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou!

Answer (score 0):

Testar se "s" != NULL é a mesma coisa que apenas testar "s".

Assim:

```
+ (NSString*) getText:(sqlite3_stmt *)stmt idx:(int)idx {
char *s = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, idx);
if (s)
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:s];
return nil;
```

}

O código fica mais limpo.
Veja bem, ambas as maneiras estão corretas. A segunda é apenas uma forma implícita de testar a mesma coisa.
Ah! Também funciona se precisar negar a condição:

```
if(!s)...
```