# Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, sqlite, swift, xcode

Tive a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

No seguinte trecho de código:

```
    // Lê uma coluna do tipo String no (BANCO DE DADOS)
    func getString(stmt:COpaquePointer, index:CInt) -> String {

       let cString  = SQLiteObjc.getText(stmt, idx: index)

       let s = String(cString)

       return s
    }
```

Por que isso ocorre?

Comment: O problema é idêntico ao que ocorreu em sua [outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70991/4337). Você está tentando iniciar uma `String` passando um valor nulo, no caso você precisa verificar se `cString` tem algum valor.

Comment: Obrigado! Pensei que eu não pudesse fazer a mesma verificação, sendo que o valor fosse nulo.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que dá pra ver, o resultado da chamada de SQLiteObjc.getText pode vir vazio, então seria interessante sua função retornar uma string optional. Eu reescrevi o código para tratar o erro. Espero que ajude!

```
func getString(stmt:COpaquePointer, index:CInt) -> String? {

    if let cString = SQLiteObjc.getText(stmt, idx: index) {
        return String(cString)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```